# My navigation is acting kind of funny: setting a width won't work and it jumps

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I created a JSFiddle to show.
http://jsfiddle.net/nv78t/

What's happening is that I want the list items to be of a uniform length, 150px, however when I set it, the animation seems to switch from the left to the right, which is what I don't want. Also, on page load, the links are a certain margin space apart, but seem to jump to a different margin space. I want them to stay where they are, and only the width to change from a uniform width. What am I doing wrong with this? Everything I've tried to tweak has given negative results.

I've posted all the code corresponding to this below.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="#" id="nav1" class="nav">Main</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="nav2" class="nav">Double Rainbow</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="nav3" class="nav">Monochrome Rainbow</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS like this,

```
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
#leftcolumn ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    /*width: 150px;*/
}
#leftcolumn li {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    display: block;
    /*width: 150px;*/
}
#leftcolumn a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#leftcolumn a:visited {
    color: white;
}
#nav1 {
    background-color: #FF2300;
    padding: 7px;
}
#nav2 {
    background-color: #FF9A00;
    padding: 7px;
}
#nav3 {
    background-color: #FFE800;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

and my JQuery like this:

```
$(".nav").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "250px"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "150px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within each of the links, wrap the text in a `<span>` element, like so:

```
<li><a href="#" id="nav1" class="nav"><span>Main</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="nav2" class="nav"><span>Double Rainbow</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="nav3" class="nav"><span>Monochrome Rainbow</span></a></li>
```

And use the following CSS declarations (I've stripped it back to focus on the problem):

```
#leftcolumn {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
#leftcolumn ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
}
#leftcolumn li {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#leftcolumn a {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px;
}
#leftcolumn a span {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
}
#nav1 {
    background-color: #FF2300;
}
#nav2 {
    background-color: #FF9A00;
}
#nav3 {
    background-color: #FFE800;
}
```

The key property here is `display: inline-block;`. Anchor tags by default are inline elements so will ignore dimension properties. jQuery's `animate()` function must change the `display` property of its target elements in order to produce the correct behaviour.

Edit: Wrapping the link text in an inner `<span>` element with block behaviour and a set width will prevent the text moving in this scenario, as it is the outer `<a>` tag that is being animated.

Comment: Ah, that's fantastic. Is there a way to make the width longer from the opposite side?

Comment: Updated my answer - I think this is what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Check here, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/nv78t/5/, you want like this?

## CSS

```
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    background:#dfdfdf;
}
#leftcolumn ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    float:right;
}
#leftcolumn a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#leftcolumn a:visited {
    color: white;
}
#leftcolumn li {
    width: 150px;
    float:right;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px;
}
a#nav1,
a#nav2,
a#nav3{
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float:right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align:right;
}
#nav1 { background-color: #FF2300; }
#nav2 { background-color: #FF9A00; }
#nav3 { background-color: #FFE800; }
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#leftcolumn a {float:right}
```

You'll notice that when you mouseover each item and back again, you get the animations queuing up. If you don't want this;

Change

```
$(this).animate
```

to

```
$(this).stop().animate
```

**Fixes:**

With CSS fix : http://jsfiddle.net/nv78t/2/

With CSS fix and jQuery fix : http://jsfiddle.net/nv78t/3/

Comment: The float:right didn't seem to work, it's still starting off in the wrong place and the width won't set at 150px.

Comment: The problem is, the hover animation works fine, but because the links are by default - display:inline. When you unhover they are being set to 150px width, rather than going back to display:inline (Non fixed width)